# Node Express Routing not working as exprected

Tags: node.js, express, routes, pug

`app.js:`

```
var routes = require('./routes');

app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', routes.index);
```

And some more use statements.

`./routes/index.js:`

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

};

exports.impressum = function(req, res){
    res.render('impressum', { title: 'Impressum' });
};
```

And in `./views/` I have `index.jade` and `impressum.jade`

Calling `http://localhost:3000/` shows the index.

But I can't reach the impressum page at all. Any clues?

Comment: where did you put `app.get('/impressum', routes.impressum);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As damphat mentions you need to wire up a route to your impressum page.  You'll have to put in a route for each page you want your app to respond to.

I did a [screencast that goes into Express routing](http://www.learnallthenodes.com/episodes/4-cleaning-up-with-express-routing).  You can check it out-- it might be of use.  Also [the Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB) is useful.